# How do I uninstall Adobe Reader 9 for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader spews files everywhere plus it hijacks Safari.

I can't believe there is no uninstaller for this app?

Google shows no good info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to just delete the application and its associated files. [This thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7397487) has a list of things and discussion of what to delete. Make sure to remove `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin` if you've [installed the Safari in-browser viewer from Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/870/cpsid_87060.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did see that, but I wasn't sure what changed from version 8 to version 9. I imagine since it was a major revision, at least some of that list will be out of date.

Comment: I followed these instructions with a spotlight search open looking for anything "adobe", "acrobat", or "reader". Seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

For most applications, OS X doesn't have installers, or uninstallers, per se. Usually, you simply drag the application Icon to the Trash Can. The app icon (Something.app) is a whole directory. However, this doesn't work for every program.

To remove all traces of a program, if it littered the OS with other files, you might need a program like [AppCleaner.app](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/) or you can follow [this guide](http://www.rawcomputing.co.uk/macuninstall.html) for more information.

Comment: Reader spews files everywhere plus it hijacks Safari. It also didn't come with an uninstaller.

Comment: Also App Cleaner and App Zapper don't find all of the files. They just search the preferences folcer and application support folder. They miss everything else.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe's site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408814.html)

**To uninstall Acrobat 9 in Mac OS**

1. Double-click the Acrobat Uninstaller file, located in the Adobe Acrobat 9 folder.
2. Follow the on-screen instructions to uninstall Acrobat.
3. In the Authenticate dialog, type the user name and password for an administrator account and click OK. Note: The uninstaller removes only Adobe Acrobat 9 and 9.1 files from the system.  It does not remove Adobe Reader files, Acrobat user data, or files that are shared with other Adobe applications.

Comment: There is no uninstaller with Reader, which is strange. but I scoured my system for it before I posted.

Comment: I also reinstalled reader to see if it would install the "uninstaller", but it did not, I just ended up with 2 copies of reader.

Comment: Corey - hmm, so much for RTM, I'll see if I can contact adobe.

Comment: I created an account on their website, posted a comment (with a link to this site) and down-voted their article. Anyone else want to do the same?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could even do that! I will vote it down also

Comment: It gets better. Check out: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2176089#2176089

* they made me create an adobe account, I commented about this discussion.
* they "approved" my post, which actually deleted it.
* I went to the forum in the "approval" email they gave me, and found that thread, where nobody has answered the question (posted in April).

Can I say... WEAK!

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution. Use App Cleaner. First- Drag Adobe Reader from your applications folder into App Cleaner. Next- press "others" tab in App Cleaner- this will display Adobe Reader plug in(s). Delete any plug ins shown- then go to "applications" tab and delete all files shown.