# How do I set Preview as the PDF viewer in Safari, instead of Adobe Reader X?

Tags: mac, adobe-reader

I unfortunately have to use Adobe Reader X on my Mac.

In the past, I could set Preview as the default PDF viewer in Safari, but with Adobe Reader X, that option is disabled!

[image]

I already know that I can delete Adobe’s plug-in, but I’m pretty sure it will just come back the next time the damn thing auto-updates.

The “right” way is to change that setting, which (at least in previous versions) maintained the setting through updates. How do I do it?

Comment: It seems all solutions require root-access :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is a known issue. Adobe has [a knowledge base article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/870/cpsid_87060.html) that says:

> **Known issues**
>
> **Reader's Preferences > Internet > Display PDF in Browser is always dimmed**
>
> - To disable Safari integration, delete the AdobePDFViewer.plugin from  /Library/Internet Plug-ins
> - To reenable Safari integration, rerun the installer over the current installation. Start the Acrobat/Reader X installer from the original media, and then follow the onscreen prompts to complete the installation.

Hopefully the plug-in doesn’t come back the next time Reader updates.

Comment: Is there a way (e.g. hidden property) to "ungray" this preference setting?

Comment: Just an update if anyone stumbles upon this article. I'm running Reader 11.0.07 and the plugin to delete is /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin

Answer (score 0):

What I did was install a later version to reset it using the following steps:

1) Remover Acrobat Reader X
2) Delete plug (AdobePDFViewer.plugin) found at /Library/Internet Plug-ins
3) Go to http://get.adobe.com/reader/
4) Press "Choose a different version" under "Select your version of Mac OS:"
5) Select your operating system & language
6) Choose & download Reader 9.4 **NOT** Reader X 10.0.1
7) Install Reader 9.4
   7.1) Say no to the extension for safari plug in
   7.2) Say no to request to set as default
8) Reboot your system & preview should return to the default

Optional 9) I removed Reader 9.4 using the unistaller found in utilities and then removed any remaining folders left in applications (there was one labelled Adobe)

Hope this helps

Comment: This could work but I want to stay current with the latest version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered and a possible solution may be found in Adobe's knowledge base article as mentioned in @Nate's post.

However, a non-destructive method to disable Adobe Reader as PDF reader in Safari is to

1. Create a new folder `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins (disabled)/`
2. Move the file `AdobePDFViewer.plugin-deactivated` from `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` to the newly created folder.

This way you don't have to reinstall Adobe Reader in case you change your mind later.